# Transactions in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I need some idea in handling transactions in Entity Framework.

Let's consider a small example.

In my database I have a table `A` with auto generated identity column `id`, and I have a table `B` with a reference key to `A(id)`.

In a scenario where I need to insert data in to both tables `A` and `B`, I want to start a transaction. Lets say a new row is inserted into `A`. I need newly inserted identity (`id`) value that I need to utilize for `B` insertion.

Can someone give me lead on handling this situation? Do we need to really utilize transactions in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call SaveChanges, the updates are made in a transaction. If one fails, it is all rolled back. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx) on msdn. Particularly the "Remarks" section.

Comment: In my case i need to call the SaveChanges after the first transaction for retrieving the auto generated identity column for table A which i will use during the insertion of data into table B

Comment: If you have your foreign keys set up, the entity framework will take care of this for you. e.g. `Table1Record.Table2CollectionProperty.Add(Table2Record); Table2Record.Table1NavigationProperty = Table1Record; myContext.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Tanks for the help, only added the first line it solved the problem. I don't understand the second line(Table2Record.Table1NavigationProperty = Table1Record;), can you elaborate. It worked without second line.

Comment: Take this one-to-many example. A Person has **multiple** addresses therefore an address has **one** person. Person.Address is called a **collection** property. Address.Person is called a **navigation** property.

Comment: We can use either of the two statements to establish the relation ships. Is there any specifics to have both the statements Table1Record.Table2CollectionProperty.Add(Table2Record); Table2Record.Table1NavigationProperty = Table1Record;

Comment: @kumar. No, I was just being thorough.